# Compare an empty UITextField to nil string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextField that I am trying to compare to a string password in a class.  The problem happens when the password is nil.  According to the debugger an empty `UITextField` returns `@""` so I tried a length based appproach.

```
 NSString *pw;
 if([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text length] > 0)
     pw = room.password;

 if([pw isEqualToString:room.password])
  //do some code
```

But this still isn't working for nil passwords...ive even verified with the debugger that both `pw` and `room.password` are `nil` (see below)...whats going on?

[image]

Comment: So are you wanting to verify that both are nil, or are not nil? I'm not sure what you are asking. You said it's not working with nil passwords, then you go on to say that you've verified that both text fields are nil.

Comment: the `if` statement comparing `pw` to `room.password` is not triggering when `nil` and I don't understand why.

Comment: Because the if statement is returning false, and therefore not executing code in the statement. What is your desired outcome? What are the inputs? Are you checking to see if a user has entered text?

Comment: Right...but why is is returning false?  According to the debugger both `pw` and `room.password` are equal to `nil`, shouldn't it return true?

Comment: No, if you want it to return true, you'd have to ask if textField.text == nil

Comment: Keep in mind that if you call an Objective-C method with a nil object pointer, the method returns zero/nil.  This means that isEqualToString will always return NO if pw is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send any message to a nil object.

"If you expect a return value from a message sent to nil, the return value will be nil for object return types, 0 for numeric types, and NO for BOOL types. Returned structures have all members initialized to zero."
- Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html

Since `pw` is `nil` keep in mind, that there are no `isEqual` methods declared for that object.

Therefore, what you should do is:

```
if([pw isEqualToString:room.password] || (pw == nil && room.password == nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're sending a message to nil. That's never going to return TRUE.

pw can't respond to the `isEqualToString:` selector because it's nil.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
if (textField.text == nil) {
    //empty textField
    DoSomething();
} else {
    //textField contains text
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the strong is nil, it does not exist so you cannot compare it.